# How do i troubleshoot this MySQL error?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a simple website for a class, and I am trying to save information to my database. The error is not very specific and I do not know which part of my code I need to fix.

Error message:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

My PHP code:

```
<?php
include 'mysqli.php' ;

$result = $con->query("select * from setList s 
left join songTable t on s.SetList_ID = t.Song_ID
left join bands b on s.SetList_ID = b.Band_ID");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$setList = $_POST['setlist'];
$venue = $_POST['venue'];
$date = $_POST['dateOfShow'];
$band= $_POST['band'];

$set = $result->fetch_object();

//error handling and form
try {
    if (empty($setList) || empty($venue) || empty($date) ||         empty($band)) {
        throw new Exception(
            "All Fields Required");
    }

    if (isset($set)) {
        $id = $set->SetList_ID;

   $q = "update setList set SetList_Name = '$setList',
            Venue = '$venue', Show_Date = $date, Band_Name = '$band')";   
        }
    else{

    $q = "insert setList (SetList_Name, Venue, Show_Date, Band_Name)
        values ('$setList', '$venue', $date, '$band')";
    }

    $result = $con->query($q);
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }

     header('Location:my_set-lists.php');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo '<p class ="error">Error: ' .
    $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: You have non-matching parenthesis in  your SQL update statement: `"update setList set SetList_Name = '$setList',Venue = '$venue', Show_Date = $date, Band_Name = '$band')"`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said, I am very new to this and this is for a class project. I will keep this in mind for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly where the problem is; you have an extra `)`. Replace

```
$q = "update setList set SetList_Name = '$setList',
        Venue = '$venue', Show_Date = $date, Band_Name = '$band')";
// extra ) is here ---------------------------------------------^
```

With

```
$q = "update setList set SetList_Name = '$setList',
        Venue = '$venue', Show_Date = $date, Band_Name = '$band'";
```

Note: your next query (starting `insert setList`) is also going to fail; it should be `INSERT INTO setList...`. A decent IDE (like PHPStorm) would catch these errors for you.

Also, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You really need to be using prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said, I have very little experience. I am now getting a new error telling me Band_Name is an unknown column. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @ferrari3000 That means you don't have a column by that name. From the looks of it, you probably only have a `Band_ID` column. You should accept this answer if it helped you, then ask a new question if you run into new or different errors.